# Unable to pass data to service from component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass a parameter to a function defined in a service. The parameter is always `undefined`.

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [AuthenticationService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

credentials: {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};

constructor(private _authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

ngOnInit() { }

login() {

    this._authenticationService.login(this.credentials).subscribe(
        response => console.log(response),
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log('Done.')
    );

}
```

**authentication.service.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

constructor() { }

login(credentials) {

    console.log(credentials); // This is undefined

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing data perfectly, but the problem is you declared variable `credentials` with type `{ username: '', password: '' };`, you didn't assign value to it, which is why it is `undefined`. `:` assigns type to variable, `=` assigns value. This is what you're looking for:

```
credentials: any = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};
```

Comment: Ugh. I used `:` instead of `=`. Thanks Stefan. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @KabirRoy It happens man, don't worry. I see no reason to delete it, but you can delete it if you want, your choice. :-)